Saving to a .csv file on standalone watchOS app?
I'd like to save raw sensor data (e.g., accelerometer data) to a .csv file (or any other similar filetype) on the Apple Watch's persistent memory. My impression is that you can use CoreData, but I can't find information about the amount of memory available or local directories to write to.
I'd like to understand the amount of data I can store locally on the watch since my plan is to, at some cadence, upload this data from the standalone watch app to a server.
